# Autofac using generic objects as non-generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

I have two interfaces `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>`, the latter inherits from the former. And some class `Handler` like:

```
public class Handler
{
    public Handler(ILogger logger)
    {
    }
}
```

and I would like to tell `Autofac` to resolve and pass in an `ILogger<T>` instead of an `ILogger`. Assume I can resolve instances of both `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>`, so that's not the issue here.

I know I could pass an instance by doing:

```
builder.RegisterType<Handler>()
       .AsSelf() // assume any other suplerfluos config is also done
       .WithParameter(...);
```

There 3 overloads (at least on my version of `Autofac`) but all 3 of them somehow imply using an instance as the parameter.

I would like to do something like: `.WithParameter(typeOf(ILogger<Handler>))`

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: How would you expect this to work at runtime?  You certainly couldn't write something like this that would compile so why would you expect runtime to behave any differently?

Comment: If I were to manually create a `Handler` instance I could do `var handler = new Handler(new DefaultLogger<Handler>());` and it would work. I thought there was a way to make Autofac do that for me whenever I asked for a Handler.

Comment: Why don't you simply map `ILogger` to `DefaultLogger<Handler>()`? Or would it be `DefaultLogger<Handler2>()` for the `ILogger` that needs to be injected into `Handler2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using registration events.

```
/// <summary>
/// DI registrations for loggers.
/// </summary>
public class LoggersModule : IModule
{
    public void Configure(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry)
    {
        componentRegistry.Registered += (sender, e) =>
                                 e.ComponentRegistration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[] 
        { 
            new ResolvedParameter(
                                              (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger), 
                                              (p, i) => LoggerFactory.GetLoggerForClass(t))
        });
    }
}
```

Where `LoggerFactory.GetLoggerForClass()` essentially creates an instance of `ILogger<T>`.